# How enable graphical boot screen with splash screen on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, boot, grub2

I've been working on some cases to enable Splash Screen for Ubuntu Server 22.04.
Just in case, I tried running Ubuntu Core, which has a splash screen out-of-box, and it works fine. My idea was to exclude the hardware factor.

Here is the kernel boot arguments:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1920 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=1080 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=DC:A6:32:56:98:8E vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  console=ttyS0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 rootwait fixrtc quiet splash
```

So, `quiet splash`is present in the command line, and I thought it should be enough to start showing a graphical splash screen, but it doesn't.

The second theory was missing themes of **Plymouth** and then I installed one of them by the following:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install plymouth grub2-common
$ sudo update-grub
$ sudo reboot
```

However when I ran

```
$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 275: cannot create /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new: Directory nonexistent$
```

It's weird, but I created a folder and re-run the command without issues.

I realized that Plymouth was already installed, and grub2-common was required to add update-grub. On the following boot sequence, I still have no splash screen displayed.

Ok, I installed yet another theme from the Ubuntu (main stream):

```
$ sudo apt search plymouth
$ sudo apt -y install plymouth-theme-sabily plymouth-theme-hamara plymouth-theme-spinner
```

I installed three themes, just in case.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --display default.plymouth
default.plymouth - manual mode
  link best version is /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth
  link currently points to /usr/share/plymouth/themes/sabily/sabily.plymouth
  link default.plymouth is /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth
/usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth - priority 110
/usr/share/plymouth/themes/sabily/sabily.plymouth - priority 60

$ sudo reboot
```

There is no splash screen on the boot. :(

What else I could try to enable splash screen on Ubuntu Server 22.04?

Thanks